# Include custom file into header with org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a LaTeX file with some directives for my TeX documents (`\usepackage` and such things). Now I want to reuse this file in different org-mode files. I know I can include files with `#+include: 'path/to/some/file.tex'`, but this puts the content of the file after `\begin{document}`.

Can I somehow include a file into the header?

As suggested, here an example:

A **template.tex** file that holds the header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{customClass}
\usepackage{etex}
\title{Some Title}
\supervisor{Someone}
```

As also shown here, this uses a custom document class, which is one of the reasons why I just want to be able to include it.

Then I have a file which contains all the content (**content.org**):

```
#+INCLUDE: template.tex

* Chapter 1
** Subchapter 1
   Some content
** Subchapter 2
   More content
```

Which currently outputs (**content.tex**):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
% a lot more org-mode standard header stuff
% ...

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\vspace*{1cm}

% my template.tex file
% not where I wanted it
\documentclass[a4paper]{customClass}
\usepackage{etex}
\title{Some Title}
\supervisor{Someone}


\section{Chapter 1}
% rest of the document
% ...

\end{document}
```

So in short: I want to reuse my `template.tex` file in a few org documents to have consistent formatting. Is this possible?

Comment: Please add a MWE to show what you want to achieve and assist the helpers to help you.

Comment: You are right, that might have been a good idea for me to think of. :) Added one now.

Comment: Perhaps `LaTeX_HEADER: \input{template}`?

Comment: It does the right thing and simply outputs the `\include{template}` into the header, but still outputs it's own header which confuses latex.

Comment: I'm still on a < 8.0 version of `org`, but don't you want to set this in your `.emacs`?  That is, with `(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes <stuff> )`.

Comment: That works! I had to add a few options to keep org-mode from outputting too many things, but it works now.

    #+LATEX_CLASS: myarticle
    #+bind: org-export-latex-title-command ""

    #+OPTIONS: toc:nil

Answer (score 7):

While I do not know a way to do this with a LaTeX file, you can use `#+SETUPFILE: file` (http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html) to include an external org file in exporting. Then you can use `#+LaTeX_HEADER:` in the external org file.

For example, with the following in `content.org`:

```
#+SETUPFILE: template.org
```

and with the following in `template.org`:

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS: customClass
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper]
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{etex}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \title{Some Title}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \supervisor{Someone}
```

When you export `content.org`, they will be included as a part of the preamble of `content.tex`.

Answer (score 3):

The latex header org uses for export is stored in `org-format-latex-header`, which you can modify as you like.  According to the help:

> It is imperative that this header make sure that no page number
>   appears on the page.  The package defined in the variables
>   `org-latex-default-packages-alist' and`org-latex-packages-alist'
>   will either replace the placeholder "[PACKAGES]" in this
>   header, or they will be appended.

Answer (score 2):

You can create file local variable in your org file to disable default header,then there is no it's own header outputs which confuses latex code that you want.

```
# Local Variables:
# org-latex-default-packages-alist: nil
# org-latex-with-hyperref: nil
# org-latex-packages-alist: nil
# End:
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your answer is a little bit short. Could you elaborate a little bit on it ;-)